# Why is the running time of this code O(nlogn)?

Tags: big-o

This is an exercise from the course Algorithms, Part 1 on Coursera. They said the answer is O(N log N). I do not get why:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i*2)
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j = j*2)
        for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
            sum++;
```

Could anybody please tell me how many times the inner most loop is running and why the answer is O(N log N)?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Which complexity would *you* expect?

Comment: That is hard to answer since I do not realise how many times the inner most loop runs. But I would have thought that the two outer most loops would run log n times respectively.

Comment: It is a geometric progression 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ... (where the base first term a=1, and the multiplier r=2) see this page: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/atp2/geoseq.htm

Comment: I am sorry if I am asking stupid questions, but how is finding the geometric progression going to help me figuring out how many times the loops run? Could you give an example by connecting this geometric progression with the code above?

Answer (score 3):

The outer loop runs log(N) times.
The both inner loops run combined Sum_{x=1}^{log(N)} 2^x times, where each summand represents one iteration of the middle loop.
Using the geometric sum formula this makes in total log(N)*(1-2^(log(N)+1))/(1-2) = log(N)*(2N-1) iterations, which is obviously O(N*logN)

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyse (rewritting `j`  as `J`)

```
for (int J = 1; J <= N; J = J*2)
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
```

Suppose `N = 2^n`. The values of `J` are `2^0, 2^1, 2^2, \ldots, 2^n`.
The loop with `k` executes `J` times so when `J = 2^j`, it execute `2^j` times.
In total, we have

```
2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \ldots + 2^n
```

execution.
But this is the sum of a geometric progression so the sum is

```
2^0 (2^{n+1} - 1)(2 - 1) = 2^{n+1} - 1 = O(2^n) = O(N).
```

This the outer loop with `i` executes `n = \log(N)` times, we have a total of `O(N\log(N))`.

Answer (score 1):

The outermost loop's steps grow exponentially:

```
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 .... N
```

The middle loop is the same.

Both have `log(N)` (to base 2) steps.

So you got `log(N) * log(N)` so far.

The innermost loop runs `j` times where `j` is bounded/given by the middle loop each time. It is run `log(N)` times with iteration step of 1. This is a series:

```
j=1:      1
j=2:      1 2
j=4:      1 2 3 4
j=8:      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
j=16:     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 16
...
j=N:      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... N
======================================
1 + 3 + 10 + 36 + ... + (1+2+3+4+5+...+N)
```

So you have `log(N) * log(N) * N` as upper bound (the innermost loop runs less steps than `N` in fact).

Thus in the end you have `O(N*log^2(N))`.

My analysis does not yield `O(N*log(N))`, but it does not mean it isn't. Maybe the innermost loop's boundary can be improved, since I simplified here with `N` as upper bound for all loops; what I mean is the two innermost loops maybe are better than `O(N*log(N))`. If you can see how they are `O(N)` then you got your solution.

Comment: But based on the answer, then j = 1, j = 2, j = 3, j = 4, j = 5. How can it be so when j runs logarithmically? Should it not be j = 1, j = 2; j = 4, j = 8 ... So I do not understand why j = log(N): 1 2 3 4 5 ... log(N). Could you elaborate please? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Elyasin. I am still trying to understand the last two lines though: 

j=log(N):    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... log(N)
======================================

1 + 3 + 10 + 36 + ... + (N-1)+log(N)

Any chance you have time to explain them?

Comment: @user2399525 Sorry, I corrected again. j goes from `1 to N`, but in exponential steps. So it loops loops `log(N)` times.

Comment: Check and let me know. I am not able to get to your solution really. I reconsidered and the best I can come up with is `O(N*log^2(N))` at the moment.

Comment: O(N*log^2(N)) is also the solution I am coming up with. But that is not the answer according to this course on Coursera. But thank you!

Comment: @user2399525 Would you be so kind and let us know the solution once you receive it. That would interest me really. I reckon there is a subtle technique that is useful.